# Is it possible to check whether Adobe Acrobat is used to open the pdf or not?

Tags: adobe, layers

The question is in the title itself. I want to add some layered structure in my pdf which are shown properly only in Adobe Acrobat (and Foxit partially). Is it possible to show the layered structure only when the user opens it in Adobe Acrobat (or Foxit reader possibly) and replace it with other text otherwise (when opened in browser, SumatraPDF, etc.)?

Edit: The following is an example of what I want to show if the pdf is opened in Adobe Acrobat:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ocgx2}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \switchocg{Eg1}{Example1}\qquad\switchocg{Eg2}{Example2}\qquad\switchocg{Eg3}{Example3}
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{ocg}[radiobtngrp=eg]{Eg1}{Eg1}{0}
        First example
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Explanation 11
            \item Explanation 21
            \item Explanation 31
        \end{itemize}
    \end{ocg}
    \begin{ocg}[radiobtngrp=eg]{Eg2}{Eg2}{0}
        Second example
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Explanation 12
            \item Explanation 22
            \item Explanation 32
        \end{itemize}
    \end{ocg}
    \begin{ocg}[radiobtngrp=eg]{Eg3}{Eg3}{0}
        Third example
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Explanation 13
            \item Explanation 23
            \item Explanation 33
        \end{itemize}
    \end{ocg}
    \end{center}

%%Content if it's not opened in adobe acrobat.
%The first second and third examples are as follows:
%\begin{itemize}
%   \item Explanation 11
%   \item Explanation 12
%   \item Explanation 13
%   \item Explanation 21
%   \item Explanation 22
%   \item Explanation 23
%   \item Explanation 31
%   \item Explanation 32
%   \item Explanation 33
%\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you can add some Javascript (which works in Acrobat, but not in most other viewers) to show the extra layers. Can you add a small example document to your question to illustrate what kind of structure you have in mind?

Comment: @Marijn, Added that.